# How to "stream" multiple object fields from an ArrayList to an array of double using mapToDouble?

Tags: java

I have multiple object of class `org.joml.Vector3f` stored in an `ArrayList<Vector3f>`. The class has 3 float fields: `x`, `y` and `z`. I would like to save them all in a `java.nio.DoubleBuffer` so I wanted to do something like this:

```
public void myFunction(ArrayList<Vector3f> vertices) {
      // Some code here
      DoubleBuffer positionbuffer = DoubleBuffer.wrap(vertices.stream().mapToDouble(i -> {i.x, i.y, i.z}).toArray());
      // Some code here
}
```

But this is not a legal/possible way to do it.

Is there a way to use `mapToDouble` and do something in the parenthesis so that I can retrieve and store every single field of every single Vector3f in the `ArrayList` to an array of double?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
DoubleBuffer positionbuffer = DoubleBuffer.wrap(
        vertices.stream()
                .map(i -> new double[]{i.x, i.y, i.z})
                .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream)
                .toArray());
```